# Get div attribute value on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get value of div attribute. Like I want to know whether the div is `"display:block;"` or `"display:none"` at the time of page load. If "display:block;" then it will be "display:block;" after the page load again if not then "display:none". Can anyone help me with jquery method or code?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){$("#divId").css("display")});

Comment: "[hide it] after the page load again" I don't think this is possible, unless you, perhaps, persist some data in your browser's webstorage?

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var x =$("#divId").css("display");

        alert(x);
    });
</script>
```